# KafkaProducer (0.9): Single producer multiple topics. Potential problems?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We’re currently using one producer per topic. We’re considering switching to one producer for multiple topics for obvious reasons.

Now, is there a case where one topic might be slower for some reason, and not the others? And if there is such a case, how would it play out with a single producer producing to multiple topics? Would it affect throughput of other topics?

Are there any other cases where using a single producer for multiple topics might not be a good idea?

Thanks !

Update:
Here's what we have tried so far:

We briefly looked at the code and here's what we understand:
Kafka server accepts a a batch of messages for each topic partition. Map[TopicAndPartition, MessageSet]

It tries to process the entire batch within the configured timeout, and sends back a response containing successful and failed records.

Now let's look at what can go wrong on a topic level, and how that would affect the entire batch:

1) Not all replicas available for a topic: 
Let's say a batch contains data for three topics: test1, test2, test3. 
For test3, not all replicas are available. This case will be detected by the leader instantly, and it will fail the records. In this case, the batch won't be delayed, and throughput for test1, and test2 won't be affected.

2) Replicas for a topic are slow. 
Let's say that the replicas for only test3 are slow. In this case, replicating messages for test3 will take time, which in turn will delay the entire batch, thus affecting the throughput of topics test1 and test2.

What else can go wrong?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean from multiple producer to a single producer in the same application?

Using a single producer should not have downside

- You have a single connection to each broker (where you have n* for n producer)
- You will batch messages more efficiently

There may be some downsides, which are solvable by conf:

- if you have quota on broker side which where configured to control broker throughput, as you will produce more data with a single producer, you may hit the quota.
- You may have to modify your conf a bit (this depends which client you use) as you will produce more data - `buffer.memory` on java producer for example, and if you want to batch to the best, `max.request.size` and `batch.size`. This depends of your data

Comment: Thanks for the response @Treziac. Would you be able to comment on this: " is there a case where one topic might be slower for some reason, and not the others". Will that affect the throughput for other topics?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. (edit, early post)

You mean, when you had
`producer1 -> topic1`
`producer2 -> topic2`
...

and pass to
`producer -> topic1, topic2, topic3` ?
then all throughput to topics are at least the same?

If all the producer were in the same process, there should be no slower throughput except the situations I stated earlier (if you hit quota).

Comment: Also, if you improve batching to improve throughput, you may increase latency (higher throughput but higher latency). If it is vital you receive your data in say 5ms rather than 100ms, you will have to sacrifice batching a bit (but you didn't mention latency, so I assume it's ok)

Note that producer is thread safe for producing. Use it to the best. 
In your case, simply replacing the old multiple instances by a single one should be ok

Comment: Thanks for the response @Treziac. I think we feel good about the configs, batching, buffering and so on. We're just trying to identify the factors that might lead to a low throughput for all topics, just because a topic (or two) are having issues. So that we can assess the risk.